# Is it possible to simplify this sql query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got  3 tables.

`'Order details'
OrderID | Quantity | UnitPrice | ProductID
  1002  |    19    |    17     |    824
  1003  |    5     |    15     |    285
  1004  |    7     |    6      |    543`

`'Orders'
OrderID | CustomerID
  1002  |   224
  1003  |   224
  1004  |   348`

`'Customers'
CustomerID|   Name   | Phone
    224   |   John   | 235-453
    225   |   July   | 532-232`

I have to get the info about people who ordered more than 10 products with an average price less than 17. I did this, but I am not sure if it is the best approach.

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE customerid IN
   (SELECT DISTINCT customerid
    FROM orders
    WHERE orderid IN
       (SELECT orderid id
        FROM 'order details'
        WHERE 17 >
            (SELECT avg(unitprice)
             FROM 'order details'
             WHERE orderid = id
             GROUP BY orderid)
          AND 10 <
            (SELECT sum(quantity)
             FROM 'order details'
             WHERE orderid = id
             GROUP BY orderid)
        GROUP BY orderid))
```

Comment: Does "ordered more than 10 products" mean in a single order, or over all their orders?

Comment: @CL. over all their orders

Comment: What does "more than 10 produces with an average price less than 17" mean? The products you select that end up being more than 10, should have an average less than 17? Or do you mean "people who ordered more than 10 products **and** all the products they ordered end up have an average less than 17"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ["having" clause](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-having/) to filter records where the aggregates (sum, count etc.) meet a certain set of criteria.

It would be something like:

```
select customer.Name, 
       count(*), 
       avg(od.unitPrice)
from   customers c
inner join orders o on c.customerID = o.customerID
inner join orderDetails od on o.orderID = od.orderID
group by customer.Name
having count(*) > 10
and avg(od.unitPrice) < 17
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, Not sure it will work as haven't checked this.

```
SELECT 
  avg(od.unitPrice) AS AVGunitPrice,
  c.Name, 
  c.Phone
FROM Customer c 
  INNER JOIN Orders o ON o.customerID = c.CustomerID
  INNER JOIN OrderDetail od ON od.OrderID = o.OrderId
WHERE od.Quantity > 10
GROUP BY c.Name, c.Phone
HAVING avg(od.unitPrice) < 17
```